# How can I get list of mirrors in newest CPAN.pm?

Tags: perl, cpan

In old CPANs, when you run it first time, it asked you for the continent/country your're in, and then gave you a way to choose mirror.

Now it doesn't ask this question! I can of course find mirror manually, and put it in urllist, but the geographical browsing in CPAN was really handy, but I can't seem to be able to get it any longer.

Was this feature removed, or am I simply missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try entering `o conf init urllist` into the CPAN shell. This gives me the geographical menu you are looking for. (I've got cpan script version 1.9; CPAN.pm version 1.9402; perl, v5.10.0 built for i486-linux-gnu-thread-multi)

Comment: Amazing... a five year old answer and yet it still works.  <3 Perl.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~andk/CPAN-1.9402/lib/CPAN.pm#15), you have to set this manually. A list of mirrors is avaliable [here](http://www.cpan.org/SITES.html)

Comment: I know, that I can do it manually. I'm just asking if there is a way to somehow run the ability that *was* (or perhaps still is, but I can't find it) in CPAN.